# Add or remove column mapping at runtime for linq2db

Tags: linq2db

I have a scenario where if certain features are deployed then a number of columns will be there in some tables otherwise won't so the mapping of Entities and Columns is not static. I need to add/remove the mapping at runtime. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a new `MappingSchema` and pass to `DataConnection` constructor.

Consider you have the following class:

```cs
[Table]
class SampleClass
{
    [Column] public int Id    { get; set; }
    [Column] public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

To remove column from full object materialization, do the following:

```cs
var ms = new MappingSchema();

ms.GetFluentMappingBuilder()
    .Entity<SampleClass>().Property(e => e.Value).IsNotColumn();

// cache somewhere this schema

using (var db = new DataConnection(ms))
{
    var result = db.GetTable<SampleClass>().ToArray();
}
```

Remember, better to cache this new `MappingSchema` and reuse. Otherwise you will never have cache hit and you'll lose performance.

Comment: It worked but what if there are multiple tables/entities involved?

Comment: .Entity<SampleClass>().Property(e => e.Value).IsNotColumn()
.Entity<SomeOther1>().Property(e => e.Value).IsNotColumn()
.Entity<SomeOther1>().Property(e => e.Value).IsNotColumn()